# Why is there no badge for having a question shared on the SE Google+ feed?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I believe Stack Exchange maintains a [Google+ feed](https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts) and a small number of questions get posted to the feed. It seems like there should be a badge for having a question shared on the Google+ feed. There should possibly also be a badge for asking a question that gets featured as a "hot network question".

Comment: The exposure is more than enough. Usually it means lots of upvotes, which means cash reputation.

Answer (score 8):

Just because a question is featured on the Hot Network Questions list or posted to a Google+ feed doesn't immediately make it *good.* Something can be popular but not good. There was a post a few weeks ago, I don't see it now, about an SE-run Twitter account posting a question that had close votes. Some things slip through even human-driven systems, and the Hot Network Questions list is just that much more volatile.

Badges are used to promote people posting content that's well-received (or policing content that they messed up on), but just because something gets shared, even officially, doesn't necessarily mean that it's worthy of commemoration. Sure, of course, that's the goal, and most of the time it works out that way, but not always.

And in any event, the questions that rightfully end up on either of those lists should, theoretically, already be receiving at least one badge for their votes, which are (theoretically) a much more meaningful measure of their merit.

Not to mention, the gamification of the badges system is meant to promote good content or actions, but there's nothing a user can do to have their question featured through either of these mediums. You can "coerce" votes by posting awesome stuff, but you can't coerce postings on Stack Exchange social media sites. It would be more or less arbitrary who wound up with these badges.